# Empty variable output using Twig

Tags: twig, slim

I have a slim/paris/twig application and I have a strange problem with the output.

This is my code:

```
The title: {{ share.title }}
```

The output is nothing.

But if I use:

```
The title {{ share.title | lower }}
```

The output is:

> The title first title

`{{ share.title | raw }}` works too, but I don't want to use it because it shows accented characteres as weird characters.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks